# How to use LIKE operator in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, sql-query-store

Write an SQL query to report the patient_id, patient_name all conditions of patients who have Type I Diabetes. Type I Diabetes always starts with DIAB1 prefix.

```
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| patient_id   | int     |
| patient_name | varchar |
| conditions   | varchar |
+--------------+---------+
```

This table contains information of the patients in the hospital.

`patient_id` is the primary key for this table. `conditions` contains 0 or more code separated by spaces.

So this was my solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM Patients
WHERE conditions LIKE 'DIAB1%' OR conditions LIKE '%DIAB1%' ;
```

**It worked  correctly for all these conditions**

| patient_id | patient_name | conditions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Daniel | YFEV COUGH |
| 2 | Alice |  |
| 3 | Bob | DIAB100 MYOP |
| 4 | George | ACNE DIAB100 |

**except for this condition**

| patient_id | patient_name | conditions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Daniel | SADIAB100 |

And in the solution it was shown that there is a space after 1st % which would give you the correct answer:

**correct query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Patients
WHERE conditions LIKE 'DIAB1%' OR conditions LIKE '% DIAB1%' ;
```

So, can someone please explain why this query works for that particular condition (SADIAB100) and not the 1st query

Comment: What to you mean *except* for that condition? `LIKE '%DIAB1%'` will find that row.

Comment: What is your question? It's clear the two queries will produce different results because of the space.

Comment: `'conditions' contains 0 or more code separated by spaces.` -- I would strongly suggest to normalize your database model, at least to 1NF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WHERE conditions LIKE 'DIAB1%' OR conditions LIKE '% DIAB1%'

The problem this is trying to address is when a condition *contains* the keyword (DIAB1) - while you only want to match on the *beginning of* the keyword.

The naive approach fails, because it matches on "SADIAB100":

```
WHERE conditions LIKE '%DIAB1%'
```

So the workaround is to search for the keyword:

- either at the beginning of the whole string (ie at the beginning of the first condition) ; that's what `LIKE 'DIAB1%'` does
- or after another condition, in which case it is preceded by a space, so `' DIAB1%'`

Hence:

```
WHERE conditions LIKE 'DIAB1%' OR conditions LIKE '% DIAB1%'
```

A slightly neater expression is:

```
WHERE CONCAT(' ', conditions) LIKE '% DIAB1%'
```

---

Bottom line: if you are using a relational database, you should not be storing multiple values in a single row.

Instead of a CSV-like format, you should have a separate table to store the conditions, with each value on a separate row, allowing you to leverage the powerful set-based features that your product offers.

Answer (score 0):

- creating a regex pattern to find the keyword 'DIAB1'
- filtering on cases where it matches the above

```
with main as (
select
*, REGEXP_LIKE(conditions,'DIAB1') as is_relevant_patient
from <table_name>
)
select * from main where is_relevant_patient
```

- [fiddle test](https://regex101.com/r/M0Eapc/1)